# Where is the 'Input manager' menu in Unity for Mac version?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I do go around with this IDE and google for where is this menu in Mac version of Unity.

So where is it? I'm curious really.

##### This is for windows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in Edit > project setting at the top.

[image]

Comment: Oh! I really try to find this menu yesterday by 30 minutes without luck, thanks bro. My eyes could be having some problem yesterday, lmao...